# Semantic UI visibility error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

I am developing a website using Semantic UI and I stumbled upon this error:

> "Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: TypeError: "#upperDiv".visibility is not a function"

I have developed other websites using Semantic Ui and the code is 100% the same so I don't know why I get this error.

**JS file**

```
('#upperDiv')
.visibility({
onTopPassed: function(calculations) {
  console.log('Shabooom');
  $('#achievementsTitleDiv')
  .velocity("transition.slideUpBigIn", { stagger: 250 })
  .delay(750)
  .velocity({ opacity: 1 }, 750)
  $('#achievementsDiv')
  .velocity("transition.slideUpBigIn", { stagger: 250 })
  .delay(750)
  .velocity({ opacity: 1 }, 750)

}
});
```

**CSS file**

```
#achievementsTitleDiv{
  visibility: hidden;
}

#achievementsDiv{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<div id="upperDiv" class="ui stackable grid">
</div>
```

Comment: isn't `$('#upperDiv')` with a `$` in front?

Comment: OMG..... that is so silly, you are right. @taha

Comment: happens sometimes :D don't blame yourself